# Supported file types in Azure File Storage

Tags: azure, azure-files

I am wondering if there is a list of supported file types for uploading to Azure File Storage.

Particularly, what would happen if someone attempted to upload a malicious file (say, an executable) to the File Storage. Would Azure allow it, and if it did, what would happen with the .exe?

I haven't found any documentation on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering if there is a list of supported file types for
>   uploading to Azure File Storage.

As such, all kinds of files are supported by Azure File Storage. There's no restriction on the kind of files that can be uploaded/not uploaded there.

There's a threat detection service from Microsoft but is only available for Blob Storage at the time of writing this answer. You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-advanced-threat-protection?tabs=azure-portal